# Filebeat on Windows does not find logs from another drive

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have Filebeat configured on Windows Server 2012 to send logs to Elasticsearch. The `filebeat.yml` config is below (part of it).

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - E:\Go Agent\pipelines\Violet-Build-Deploy-RTCIO-Signaller\*.log
    - C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*\*.log
    - E:\logs\*.log
```

The logs matching `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*\*.log` are published successfully, but the logs which are located on `E:\` seem to not get picked up.

Some logs are below:

```
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Metrics logging every 30s
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Setup Beat: filebeat; Version: 5.0.0
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  Processors: 
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  Initializing output plugins
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Max Retries set to: 3
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Activated logstash as output plugin.
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  Create output worker
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  No output is defined to store the topology. The server fields might not be filled.
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Publisher name: Dev-Server
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Flush Interval set to: 1s
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Max Bulk Size set to: 2048
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  create bulk processing worker (interval=1s, bulk size=2048)
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO filebeat start running.
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Registry file set to: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  Windows is interactive: false
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Loading registrar data from C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO States Loaded from registrar: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Loading Prospectors: 1
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Starting Registrar
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Start sending events to output
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Starting spooler: spool_size: 2048; idle_timeout: 5s
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 DBG  exclude_files: []
2017-01-24T10:40:07+11:00 INFO Load previous states from registry into memory
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 140
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 140
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Processing 140 events
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:12+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 143
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 143
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Processing 143 events
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:17+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 84
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 84
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Processing 84 events
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:22+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 96
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 96
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Processing 96 events
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:27+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 103
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 103
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Processing 103 events
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:32+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: publish.events=566 registrar.writes=5 registrar.states.update=566 registar.states.current=3882
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 141
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 141
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Processing 141 events
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:37+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 140
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 140
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Processing 140 events
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:42+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 77
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 77
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Processing 77 events
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:47+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Flushing spooler because of timeout. Events flushed: 133
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  No events to publish
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Events sent: 133
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Processing 133 events
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Registrar states cleaned up. Before: 3882 , After: 3882
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Write registry file: C:\ProgramData\filebeat\registry
2017-01-24T10:40:52+11:00 DBG  Registry file updated. 3882 states written.
```

Comment: Can you please run Filebeat with debug enabled and update the logs you posted. To enabled debug, add `logging.level: debug` to your config file.

Comment: Cool thanks. I have just updated the log with debug level.

Comment: Or is it because there is a space in 'GO Agent' in the path?

Comment: You can surround the entire path in single quotes and try it.

Comment: Could you try running it with Filebeat 5.1.2. Looks like you are running 5.0.0.